# What's the caret (^) mean in apt-get?

Tags: apt

I'm seeing various instructions that request that you install something like:

```
apt-get install lamp-server^
```

With the oddball caret in the command. It doesn't seem to be mentioned in `apt-get` manual. What's the deal ?

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/252056/should-i-use-tasksel-tasks-in-apt-or-install-regular-metapackages

Answer (score 26):

The `^` character is not a typo. If you remove it, `apt-get` will complain that the package cannot be found.

[This article](http://tech.shantanugoel.com/2010/10/23/apt-get-caret.html) and its comments describe what the caret does:

> Well, the answer is that the caret symbol is a short form for performing a task that otherwise the program “tasksel” would have done with the given package name. tasksel is a program to ease the installation of commonly used things that go together for a particular use.

Comment: Learn something new every day.

Comment: This detail missing from the man page for 3 yrs is a terrible thing.

Comment: I don't installed tasksel in my system still it's working.

Comment: @HardikGajjar The reason is that `tasksel` is just a very useful command for working with "tasks".  You can install tasks without `tasksel`. But ([as explained here](https://askubuntu.com/a/257172/349837)) is better using `tasksel` than with the apt/caret way. Also it seems `apt-cache` doesn't provide a way to list tasks as `tasksel --list-task`.

Answer (score 14):

The **^** symbol let you install "Tasks", a set of packages. This can replace [**`tasksel`**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Tasksel#Usage_.28alternative.29), dedicated tool to work with tasks.

By doing

```
apt-get install lamp-server^
```

You are actually running installing a set of packages that would have been installed via the command (even [is not exactly the same](https://askubuntu.com/a/257172/349837)):

```
tasksel lamp-server
```

**In other words**: Tasks are very similar to meta-packages and live independently of `tasksel`. You can install tasks without installing `tasksel` package.

Comment: This is not correct. The `apt-get` command would error out on unrecognized names.

Comment: I stand corrected, it does appear that it has been used in apt-get to replace tasksel as you mentioned. I will update my answer.

Comment: Yes, but this works even without `tasksel` command being installed. And I don't have the `/usr/share/tasksel/` directory, so I can't see what other cool "tasks" are available. It's only `lamp-server^` everywhere. So where does `apt-get` take it from?