# Are Apache, PHP and MySQL installed by default?

Tags: apache2, mysql, php

Are the Apache server, PHP, and MySQL installed by default when you install Ubuntu 13.10, or should you install them separately later?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XAMPP for Apache, Mysql, PHP from this link: http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp-linux.html

its very simple easy and fast.

Try it :)

Comment: Thanks, but the idea is to install these applications natively . I know that the easiest way is to use XAMPP but then where is the fun?

Answer (score 3):

No they don't come with the desktop version of Ubuntu 13.10 by default. You have to install those three by yourself. For "how to install" please go through [this link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP) .

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to install all three is to run the lamp-server task:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

[The caret at the end means that this is running a task](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211912/whats-the-caret-mean-in-apt-get), not installing a package. There is no `lamp-server` package, so if you leave off the caret, apt-get will return the error message,

> Unable to locate package lamp-server.

The task will install Apache, MySQL, and PHP, and will also take you through the setup steps, such as creating a password for the MySQL root user.

Comment: Thank you so much TRiG. This will be a very helpfull... In fact, tha caret thing.. is new for me.

Comment: I only learned about the caret thing here, so Ask Ubuntu has helped both of us.