# Is there a quick one liner or script to install LAMP stack on a freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 server?

Tags: 20.04, apache2, mysql, php, lamp

I see many guides on installing LAMP stack on ubuntu 20. But they are all manually done one line at a time. Is there a simple script or one liner to install LAMP stack on a freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04 server?

Comment: I believe that you can still use the task selection caret `^`: see for example [What's the caret (^) mean in apt-get?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/211912/whats-the-caret-mean-in-apt-get) - or `tasksel`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The fastest way is:

`apt install lamp-server^`