# Is it possible to determine a list of manually installed Tasks (or special packages with ^ in the end) without using tasksel?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, tasksel

I see that my system has installed several tasks. Below is the output of command with `tasksel`:

```
$ tasksel --list-tasks | grep ^i
i print-server  Print server
i samba-server  Samba file server
i ubuntu-mate-core  Ubuntu MATE minimal
i ubuntu-mate-desktop   Ubuntu MATE desktop
i openssh-server    OpenSSH server
i server    Basic Ubuntu server
```

How can I get the same information using different tool(s)?
Hope to get solution **without tasksel package installed**. Only by parsing dpkg-info or something similar.

Comment: "Only by parsing dpkg-info or something similar."  Nope. Not all meta-packages are tasks and not all tasks are meta-packages. To have a 100% match you need tasksel itself installed :( Unless you want to parse a website that has them listed :)

Comment: What do packages with ^ mean? Is there some documentation?

Comment: @jarno ^ means package installation task, see at least https://askubuntu.com/a/211953/66509 . Not sure about exact man-page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is the same way that `tasksel` actually checks, but without `tasksel` you can

1. parse the list of tasks

   ```
   apt-cache dumpavail | grep ^Task: | sed -e 's/Task: //' -e 's/,./\n/g' | sort -u
   ```
2. get a list of packages installed for a task.  E.g. for the `openssh-server^` meta-package

   ```
   apt-cache show openssh-server^ | grep ^Package: | sed -e 's/Package: //' | sort -u
   ```
3. check the installation status for the list of packages installed for a task. E.g. for the `openssh-server^` meta-package

   ```
   apt-cache policy $(apt-cache show openssh-server^ | grep ^Package: | sed -e 's/Package: //' | sort -u) | grep -B 1 Installed:
   ```
4. glue it all together with bash to get task status

   ```
   for t in $(apt-cache dumpavail | grep ^Task: | sed -e 's/Task: //' -e 's/,./\n/g' | sort -u); do
     t_installed=u
     if (( $(apt-cache policy $(apt-cache show ${t}^ | grep ^Package: | sed -e 's/Package: //' | sort -u) | grep Installed: | grep -c 'none') == 0 )); then t_installed=i ; fi
     echo $t_installed $t
   done
   ```