# Switching back from Unity to KDE

Tags: unity, kde

Currently, I have a Kubuntu 20.04.

After some item I've installed **Unity**, how I can switch back to **KDE** ?

Comment: You can have multiple desktops installed; you get to select the one you'll use for that session when you login; so logout or boot, and at the *greeter* (DM login) select KDE/Plasma and you'll be using that session (*the default is usually last used, but you can change that*)

Answer (score 1):

There two ways to proceed:

- If your installation of Kubuntu is not corrupted then logout or reboot and select Plasma session on login screen.
- If Kubuntu installation is corrupted, then (re)install Kubuntu desktop back by

  ```
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install --reinstall kubuntu-desktop^
  ```

  While executing above command confirm using SDDM as login screen, then reboot and select Plasma session on login screen.

Comment: what is the meaning of ^ ?

Comment: It means task package. See https://askubuntu.com/a/211953/66509 .

Comment: I"ve don all above, but I"m still after restart landing to Unity desktop, without any option to choose...

Comment: Do you have auto-login enabled? Please manually run `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` and select SDDM here, then reboot.

Comment: I will update after reboot. Thank you!