# I switched from Ubuntu Desktop to Ubuntu Server. How do I switch back?

Tags: server, 22.04, tasksel

I accidentally switched from Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 to Ubuntu Server 22.04. Typing one command without realizing understanding it, I tried to switch to Ubuntu desktop by installing tasksel, but I couldn't update apt.

Ubuntu server image:

[image: Ubuntu server image]

The error that i face installing tasksel:

[image: The error that i face installing tasksel]

This is my terminal history after my laptop screen became red.

[image: this is my terminal history after my laptop screen became red ...]

Comment: The command: `history` may help you recall the command that you issued that is the start of the problem.

Comment: You can check my history, I edited my question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I enable the "Universe" repository?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Should I use tasksel, tasks in APT or install regular metapackages?](https://askubuntu.com/q/252056/)

Comment: Finally ifoind out that I have a released life repository... rm.old.releases.ubuntu.com could not be resolved ... for now I have no I idea where this is going

Comment: Your output in the pictures shows that the question is misleading. You didn't "accidentally switch" to a different flavor of Ubuntu. You purposefully ran several very-unwise commands that uninstalled your desktop environment. The "`purge python*`" command is particularly troubling -- that's a guaranteed system-killer, and any such instructions are highly suspicious.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to get back to ubuntu desktop, enter the following command and **reboot**.

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop^
```

Comment: What does the `^` caret at the end mean? To use the most recent compatible version? Is that not implied anyways? Or is it something like autocomplete, adapting itself for the Ubuntu-flavor's corresponding desktop environment?

Comment: @Levente https://askubuntu.com/questions/211912/whats-the-caret-mean-in-apt-get

Comment: @OrganicMarble ah, it means: do a bunch of things. `ubuntu-desktop^` is, in truth, a bunch of things. Thank you. Update: it's detailed at the bottom of this other answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/257172/1157519

Comment: +1: For the problem presented, this is a simple, safe, understandable, and highly effective solution.

Answer (score 1):

To switch from Ubuntu Server to Ubuntu Desktop I had to install the `ubuntu-desktop` package.

That was not acceptable from my repositories.

This was the repositories problem. I added some released life repositories to:

```
/etc/apt/sources.list
```

All the links were like:

```
http://mr.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

This resulted in the error :

```
mr.old-releases.ubuntu.com could not be resolved
```

I changed `mr.old-releases` to `archive` so that the link became like this:

```
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu
```

Then I updated apt:

```
sudo apt update
```

Then I installed the `ubuntu-desktop` package:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: this is my first time using the platform, thanks for the advice i will try to make it better next time