How to fix broken 24.04.1 LTS upgrade which is missing necessary software?
I just upgraded my 22.04 LTS desktop to 24.04.1 LTS.  The upgrade seemed to go fine.  On the final reboot the desktop came up in console mode.  The GUI never started.  I saw no interesting errors in the syslog.  To try to fix this I did a
sudo apt install gnome-shell

This caused the GUI to start on reboot but I totally hate this interface!  The Wayland choice is no longer there.  Just Ubuntu and Ubunti Xorg.
I don't know if this matters but the video is a RV730XT Radeon HD4670 PCI card
On further cursory inspection it appears that a LOT of apps are no longer there.  Software & Updater and the legacy terminal shell to name just two.  The printer queues all disappeared.  Brasero won't run complaining about missing libraries. There is a LOT of software that was removed and not replaced!
I probably should have waited to do this upgrade but the release is now 24.04.1 indicating that it is a tested, shaken down, stable release.  I received the popup asking if I wanted to upgrade to the latest LTS and I clicked upgrade.
This upgrade issued no errors yet has turned out to be a massive fail.  The desktop is running but is completely unusable.  I could really use some help here!
As observed in the comments, it seems that the update was massively incomplete.  Uh, yeah...
So how do I fix this without having to do a clean install?  I did try to repeat the upgrade but it responded that everything is up-to-date.  What's needed, I think, is a method of re-installing this upgrade where all of the missing software will be installed.  Is this possible?
Thanks in advance!

I agree with the comment "I probably should have waited to do this upgrade but the release is now 24.04.1 indicating that it is a tested, shaken down, stable release. I received the popup asking if I wanted to upgrade to the latest LTS and I clicked upgrade.".
I cannot revert to 22.04  or to 24.04 wthout a fresh install and don't want to go through all the tooth pulling to get back to a clean, working OS.

The default Wayland choice at login is now labeled "ubuntu", with the xorg choice labeled "ubuntu on xorg". This label change was also done on earlier releases which had the proper equipment for a wayland default.

In case you are unable to open a terminal, open a virtual terminal with ctrl + alt + f3, and then login with your username and password.

First, ensure that all the contents of /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources contain the word noble instead of jammy. If it contains jammy, replace that with noble.
sudo sed -i 's/jammy/noble/g' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo sed -i 's/jammy/noble/g' /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources

You can install all preinstalled Ubuntu packages with the commands
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^

Note that the ^ is necessary.

If you are using Xubuntu (say), then the last command should be
sudo apt install --reinstall xubuntu-desktop^

and so on. For other flavors of Ubuntu, you can use the following table. Ensure that you add ^ after the package name.



Flavour
Package




Default (Gnome (17.10 - present))
ubuntu-desktop


Budgie (simple/elegant)
budgie-desktop


Kubuntu (KDE Plasma)
kubuntu-desktop


Kylin (elegant Chinese)
ubuntukylin-desktop


Lubuntu (LXQt - light/fast)
lubuntu-desktop


MATE (GNOME 2 fork)
ubuntu-mate-desktop


Studio (Multimedia)
ubuntustudio-desktop


Unity
ubuntu-unity-desktop


Xubuntu (XFce - light/configurable)
xubuntu-desktop


Cinnamon
ubuntucinnamon-desktop


Edubuntu
edubuntu-desktop



Source.

it worked for me without --reinstall which saves some GB downloads

Without --reinstall, certain incompletely installed packages might still go missing, but it is upto you

An for those who are curious about the behavior of the caret symbol ^
https://askubuntu.com/questions/211912/whats-the-caret-mean-in-apt-get
