DNS resolver seems to stop working mid upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04
I tried several times to upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04, but it always fails with the message "The upgrade has aborted. Please check your Internet connection or installation media and try again."
The logs have a bunch of packages that fail to download when the upgrading stage starts:
Failed to fetch
http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/x/xterm/xterm_390-1ubuntu3_amd64.deb
Temporary failure resolving 'archive.ubuntu.com'

After the update fails and reverts I seem to have no internet connection until I restart my PC though it's probably just the DNS resolver because I can reach my router and raspberry-pi by their IP.
I'm guessing when the upgrade starts, some service is shut down that brings down DNS resolving with it and when the updater tries to resolve for downloads it fails. Anyone know how this could be solved? Seems like there's 7 packages affected by this.

I got past this error by hardcoding nameserver 1.1.1.1 into /etc/resolve.conf . Does seem to confirm, that systemd-resolve went down during the upgrade for some reason.
The update went through, but I was greeted with a shell and no networking so use this with caution. Probably a better way is to reinstall systemd-resolve or something before starting upgrade.
The update also removed a bunch of packages and never reinstalled them, like git and slack, probably many others. All in all not a nice experience.

Here is how to reinstall default set of packages https://askubuntu.com/q/1524989/124466

thanks, I fumbled around, trying different things and tried "sudo apt reinstall ubuntu-desktop" cuz i saw it somewhere and now everything is basically back to normal. Except a bunch of my packages were uninstalled entirely and I don't get why. Stuff like git, gedit, geany, slack were all gone.

This question is similar to: apt-get update fails to fetch files, “Temporary failure resolving …” error. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
