Messed up the update to latest Ubuntu. Can’t access desktop anymore
This is follow up thread to:
Failed update to 24.04
I tried finishing the update/upgrade, did full-upgrade and also dist-upgrade.
Was using ChatGPT to help me out navigate out of the mess I put myself into. Gave up and went to bed with my desktop up and running. Woke up to system booting only to terminal.
Right now I’m in dead spot. I don’t know what to do next and also ChatGPT sucks.
Outcome of —fix-broken install and —reinstall Ubuntu-desktop:
g g@gworkstation:~$ sudo apt --fix-broken install

A Reading package lists... Done a Building dependency tree... Done A Reading state information... Done
o 0 to upgrade, o to newly install, 0 to remove and 5 not to upgrade. 

g g@gworkstation: ^$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop i 

Reading package lists... Done a Building dependency tree... Done Я Reading state information... Done
2 Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
1 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable b distribution that some required packages have not yet been created o or been moved out of Incoming.
T The following information may help to resolve the situation:
I The following packages have unmet dependencies.
1ibpipewire-0.3-0t64 : Depends: 1ibspa-0.2-modules (= 1.0.5-1ubuntu1) but 1.0.7-3 ubuntu22.04 is to be installed
3E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. 

g gagworkstation: "$ sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

A Reading package lists... Done a Building dependency tree... Done
• Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have 1 requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable b distribution that some required packages have not yet been created oor been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
T The following packages have unmet dependencies.
libpipewire-0.3-0t64 : Depends: 1ibspa-0.2-modules (= 1.0.5-1ubuntu1) but 1.0.7-3 ubuntu22.04 is to be installed
3E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

Outcome of sudo apt-get updated:
g@gworkstation:^$ sudo apt-get update Ign: 1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease Ign:3 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease Ign:4 https://repository.mullvad.net/deb/stable jammy InRelease Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease Ign: 1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease Ign:3 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease Ign:4 https://repository.mullvad.net/deb/stable jammy InRelease Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease Ign: 1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease Ign:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease Ign:3 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease Ign:4 https://repository.mullvad.net/deb/stable jammy InRelease Ign:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease Ign:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
3 Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease
Temporary failure resolving
*archive.ubuntu.com'
3 Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease
Temporary failure resolving
"archive.ubuntu.com"
1 Err:3 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease
Temporary failure resolving
*brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com'
3 Err:4 https://repository.mullvad.net/deb/stable jammy
InRelease
Temporary failure resolving
*repository.mullvad.net'
3 Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease
Temporary failure resolving *archive.ubuntu.com"
3 Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Temporary failure resolving
*archive.ubuntu.com'
A Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble/InRelease
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-updates/InRelease
Release temporary rallure resolvive aunteubuntu. com
Temporary tallure resolving
W:
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-backports/InRelease
*archive.ubuntu.com*
W:
Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/noble-security/InRelease
Temporary failure resolving
W: Failed to fetch https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com/dists/stable/InRelease
Temporary failure resolving
W: Failed to fetch https://repository.mullvad.net/deb/stable/dists/ jammy/InRelease
Temporary failure resolving repository.mullvad.net"
*brave-browser -apt-release.s3.brave.com'
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

I reached the end of possible solutions I could come up on my own. Tried booting to grub recovery mode, shift does nothing, when I repeatedly press ESC I access grub command line. No gui or anything, so I didn’t proceed with worry I could mess up further. I would be thankful for any possible advice what to do next here in order to avoid losing access to files I have on my desktop.

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. This is a question answer site. Please don't ask multiple questions about the same problem. Edit your first question and add the information we ask for inside that question. When you copy and paste from the terminal, format the pasted text as code using the {_} icon above the edit window.

@user68186 Thank you for help. This is completely different issue though, so decided not to edit previous thread. Hope you understand.

Andrew, you should post ithose logs in the Pastebin https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Pastebin and you should edit your first question with their address and if you want to add anything, and preferably delete this one.

@amar if I may ask, is code not readable right now? Thanks for your help, I’ll update it soon.
It’s hard to do anything without working desktop right now.

It was before user68186 fixed it, but followup of question when it is the same is done the way I described it, you got an answer to your main question, follow up on that too.

And if the answer helps you accept it https://askubuntu.com/help/no-one-answers

Andrew did you solve your issue?

No, I didn’t. Unfortunately I’m stuck. I replied in other thread I created. Thank you.

Well the only advice I can give now if you tried this https://askubuntu.com/questions/1524989/major-software-missing-after-24-04-1-lts-upgrade too is boot up with a USB of Ubuntu and use Try Ubuntu, take your time and backup everything you want and then do a new installation.

Right now I booted to live system and I can’t seem to find any of my data. My original Ubuntu installation was fully encrypted. Is there any guide how I can access my files? So far figured out I need to browse nautilus with root privelages. Managed to run “sudo nautilus” from terminal, but can’t find any files I had.

Update. Managed to mount my encrypted disk on live usb. Now trying to figure out how to prevent losing any data and what to copy exactly.

Ok, Once you finished with the install and everything works out, please add an answer here so that others can get the help if they need it.
