ubuntu 24.04.1 firefox not launching
I did a clean install of 24.04.1 . Things were fine for a few days. Then a dialog box came up saying something to the effect that there were a few additions to be installed. So I triggered the install. When it rebooted, it came up in raw terminal display (this seems to be a bug in the ubuntu additions install) for tty1. To get the GUI back I did:
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=wayland dbus-run-session gnome-session
This resulted in a very odd partial GUI, so I ended up doing:
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure gdm3
    sudo service gdm3 start

and reboot.
Then it came up in the standard ubuntu GUI and applications I tried seemed to work, everything seemed good, except for firefox. On trying to launch it in the terminal, it gives:
$ firefox
Gtk-Message: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is 
provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.
Error: cannot open display: :0

It looks like in my attempt to get a GUI back, I messed up something with the display.
Note that:
$ echo $XDG_SESSION_TYPE
wayland

and this problem occurs whether starting the snap or the deb version of firefox.
Any help would be appreciated.

You need to add to the question what it is you did to get the GUI back.

Does it help if you replace the snap firefox with the apt package? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22/1404401#1404401

Solved it. The answer was in this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1524989/major-software-missing-after-24-04-1-lts-upgrade . I ran sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^ and that worked.

There was a problem with the ubuntu 24.04.1 install that others are mentioning. Specifically this question:
Major software missing after 24.04.1 LTS upgrade
The solution was in it, to run:
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^
and then reboot.
Firefox then worked properly, and seemingly, so did everything else and the GUI looked ok.
