Visual problem in Nautilus in Ubuntu 24.04
After updating to Ubuntu 24 and using GNOME, I encountered a visual issue with the Nautilus file manager. The file top bar seem misaligned or cut off, as shown in the attached screenshot.
Is anyone else facing a similar issue? I would appreciate any suggestions or fixes to resolve this problem.


There is an issue with upgrades to 24.04 currently and has currently been disabled. See this link to a post by Chris Guiver who is a regular poster on AU. There will be a fix in time,

Which theme are you using? Update the theme macos theme to its latest version. Also check out https://askubuntu.com/questions/1524989/major-software-missing-after-24-04-1-lts-upgrade/1525026#1525026 to install all necessary packages

I am having the same issue. It seems the sidebar has issues in both Settings and Nautilus.
Settings has very odd gray bars when selecting something in the sidebar.

And Nautilus has the same problem plus alignment problems:

Kernel 6.8.0-45-generic
Resolution: 3440x1440
DE: GNOME 46.0
WM: Mutter
WM Theme: Adwaita
Theme: Yaru [GTK2/3]
Icons: Yaru [GTK2/3]
CPU: Intel i7-9750H
GPU: Intel CoffeeLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics 630]
GPU: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 Mobile / Max-Q

I have tried NVIDIA graphics drivers 535, 550, 560 (using graphics ppa) without success. I have also tried both Wayland and X11. With Wayland, the odd gray bars for selecting are gone, but the sidebar is still misaligned.
