Issue with changing keyboard layout in Firefox, Kate, Konsole and other software after 24.04 upgrade
Week ago I upgraded from 22.04 to 24.04. Had almost zero issues, but now I noticed something weird.
I am using two keyboard layouts and switching between them using Alt+Shift shortcut.
When I am trying to type anything on non-english layout in Google Sheets via Firefox, nothing happens. I have to double click into cell first, then I can type.
If I use english layout, no issues at all.
For debugging purposes in system settings I added third layout. Surprisingly when I alt-tab into Firefox, I can not even choose that third layout. It is not there! I am talking about system tray icon.
Actually that issue (missing keyboard layout) repeats for most of the software (Kate, Phpstorm, Slack, even Konsole). Chromium is not affected somehow: I can see, choose and actually type into Chromium using any added keyboard layout.
To clarify: In Firefox and other software I can use layout#1 and layout#2, but not layout#3. In Google Sheets specifically I can choose layout#2, but then nothing happens when I'm typing.
If I go into System settings - Input Devices - Keyboard, then I can use any layout in Test Area.
My system is
Operating System: Kubuntu 24.04
KDE Plasma Version: 5.27.11
KDE Frameworks Version: 5.115.0
Qt Version: 5.15.13
Kernel Version: 6.8.0-44-generic (64-bit)
Graphics Platform: X11
Processors: 8 × Intel® Core™ i7-4770 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Memory: 15,6 GiB of RAM
Graphics Processor: NVIDIA GeForce GTX 970/PCIe/SSE2
Manufacturer: MSI
Product Name: MS-7850
System Version: 1.0

And I can confirm I had no issues on this machine using 22.04. Also no issues on my laptop with 22.04.

Can you try https://askubuntu.com/questions/1524989/major-software-missing-after-24-04-1-lts-upgrade/1525026#1525026, but replace ubuntu-desktop^ with kubuntu-desktop^?

@ArchismanPanigrahi thanks for suggestion. It did not help. Also in process of reinstallation, apt decided to remove Veracrypt for some reason.

Consider fresh installing kubuntu 24.04 using a USB drive

That would be last resort :)

Finally I found a solution. Apparently, there is some kind of conflict between ibus and... something?
What worked for me:
sudo apt remove ibus

At this point apt also removes zoom which I installed earlier from deb file. It is ok. We will reinstall it, but this time use snap, because we don't want ibus to come back:
sudo snap install zoom-client

It's done. Everything works fine.
P.S. I also experimented with fcitx5, but it seems this package is not necessary. However, as I noticed, if I boot into Live Kubuntu 24.04 from USB-stick, fcitx5 is installed by default. So I am not 100% sure if I should add it and why.
