Upgrade to 24.04.1 resulted in unstable wifi connection
I just upgraded to 24.04.1 from the previous release and everything is really great so far, except that my wifi connection keeps cutting out.  I've surfed the web for solutions to this and see that others have had similar experiences but so far can't find a fix.
I'm on a Dell Precision 7510 that I've pumped the RAM up to 32GB, and my wifi speed here at home is super fast.  I really shouldn't be having this problem, so I figure it's something simple right under my nose.
Can anyone please point it out to me please?

Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1524989/how-to-fix-broken-24-04-1-lts-upgrade-which-is-missing-necessary-software/1525026#1525026

That seems to be a different issue, though I did try the part about replacing jammy with noble.

Try reinstalling the packages as described in that answer and let us know if that helped. If it does not, please try Ubuntu 24.04.1 from a live USB, and let us know if the issue is present there as well

Thank you for your suggestions.  It would take me hours and hours to transfer all my data, so I didn't want to try a fresh install..

OK, have reinstalled packages as per instructions.  Will report back accordingly.

That did not do it for me.

I have similar issue with the 24.04.1 LTS.
Wifi is connected but sometimes internet connection goes off also a question mark is shown along with the wifi symbol on top bar.
you should try this https://gist.github.com/UbuntuEvangelist/e36f6a1a9ef7cb0a0b24e592eb925b68
i have done this few minutes back and seeing no much issues right now. will update if it did'nt work.

Something is not clear to me in these instructions.  When I check for wireless drivers they seem to be present:

XXX:~$ sudo lshw -C network
*-network
description: Wireless interface
product: Wireless 8260
vendor: Intel Corporation
physical id: 0
bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
logical name: wlp2s0
version: 3a
serial: e4:a4:71:16:e7:98
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-45-generic firmware=36.ca7b901d.0 8000C-36.ucode ip=192.168.1.114 latency=0 link=yes - etc.

The next step is to install missing drivers.  Is this done regardless of the results from the previous step?

Never mind.  Got impatient and just went ahead.  Will report back when I know something.

Well, it's been over half an hour with a stable connection, so I'm thinking this worked.  It was cutting out on me every few minutes.

OK, so it's cut out on me three times in the last couple of hours.  It's better but not fixed.
