"Oh no! Something has gone wrong"
I am pretty stupid guy who regrets ever installing ubuntu, but i desperately need help.
I was upgrsding for 22.04 to 22.04.1 (the LTS) or whatever. I didnt touch anything in the upgrade process.
Then it went to this white screen saying oh no.
I follow this link, and then this link to access my username and password because i use the gui thing and never the command line. But now after restarting my computer a few times to try accessing the grub menu, the oh no screen doesnt let me do the ctrl alt f3 to access the command line anymore.

Open a virtual terminal with ctrl+alt+f4 and try https://askubuntu.com/q/1524989/124466. If it does not work, you have have to reinstall 24.04.1

Ctrl Alt f4 never worked. I fixed my problem somehow though, one of the times i restarted it let me do the ctrl alt f3 for some reason, i dunno why it didnt let me before, and I just kept putting in potential passwords and usernames i might have named myself until it stuck. It helps that ubuntu doesn't shut the system permanently if you failed 20 times to log in.

Restart your computer.
Immediately after your system starts booting, press and hold the Shift key (or Esc on some systems) until the GRUB menu appears.
Then choose recovery mode. Then you can use root user. And try the options in above discussions you mentioned

I couldn't get GRUB to appear with shift. Esc brought up the bios menu for all the F# keys.
