Error upgrading from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04: ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'
I am trying to upgrade ubuntu server 22.04 to 24.04, but I can not overcome the broken package error.
I searched for a solution to my problem and tried multiple solutions as recommended in other posts but no positive results.
main.log ERROR:
ERROR Dist-upgrade failed: 'E:Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.'

apt.log Broken list
Broken coreutils:amd64 Breaks on usrmerge:amd64 < 25ubuntu2 @ii mK > (< 39)
Broken python3:amd64 Conflicts on python3-distutils:amd64 < 3.10.8-1~22.04 @ri mK Ib >
Broken liblxqt1:amd64 Breaks on liblxqt0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ri mK > (< 0.99)
Broken libfm-qt14:amd64 Breaks on libfm-qt9:amd64 < 0.17.1-0ubuntu2 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 Conflicts on libtss2-mu0:amd64 < 3.2.0-1ubuntu1.1 @ii gK >
Broken wireplumber:amd64 Conflicts on pipewire-media-session:amd64 < 0.4.1-2ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken liblxqt-globalkeys1:amd64 Breaks on liblxqt-globalkeys0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 0.99.0)
Broken libkwinglutils14:amd64 Breaks on libkwinglutils13:amd64 < 4:5.24.7-0ubuntu0.2 @ii mK >
Broken libkf5screen-data:amd64 Breaks on libkf5screen7:amd64 < 4:5.24.4-0ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 4:5.27.0~)
Broken libkwineffects14:amd64 Breaks on libkwineffects13:amd64 < 4:5.24.7-0ubuntu0.2 @ii mK Ib >
Broken pipewire-audio:amd64 Conflicts on pulseaudio:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 -> 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umU >
Broken libqtermwidget5-1:amd64 Breaks on libqtermwidget5-0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > (< 0.99.0)
Broken liblxqt-globalkeys-ui1:amd64 Breaks on liblxqt-globalkeys-ui0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > (< 0.99.0)
Broken systemd-resolved:i386 Depends on libsystemd-shared:i386 < none | 255.4-1ubuntu8.4 @un umH > (= 255.4-1ubuntu8.4)
Broken libiw30t64:amd64 Conflicts on libiw30:amd64 < 30~pre9-13.1ubuntu4 @ii mK > (< 30~pre9-16.1ubuntu2)
Broken libsgutils2-1.46-2:amd64 Breaks on libsgutils2-2:amd64 < 1.46-1ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii mK > (< 1.46-3ubuntu2)
Broken pipewire-alsa:amd64 Conflicts on pulseaudio:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 -> 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umU >
Broken libkpmcore12:amd64 Breaks on libkpmcore11:amd64 < 21.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii mK >
Broken libgs-common:amd64 Breaks on libgs9-common:amd64 < 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9 @ii mK > (< 10)
Broken libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 Depends on gnome-desktop3-data:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu1 -> 44.0-5build2 @ri umU > (< 43~)
Broken libfwupdplugin5:amd64 Depends on libfwupd2:amd64 < 1.7.9-1~22.04.3 -> 1.9.24-1~24.04.1 @ii umU > (= 1.7.9-1~22.04.3)
Broken libgs9:amd64 Depends on libgs9-common:amd64 < 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9 @ii mR > (= 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9)
Broken python3.10-venv:amd64 Depends on python3.10-distutils:amd64 < none @un mH >
Broken libpulsedsp:amd64 Depends on libpulse0:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 -> 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umU > (= 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2)
Broken libmutter-10-0:amd64 Depends on libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 3.36.0)
Broken gir1.2-mutter-10:amd64 Depends on libmutter-10-0:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu8 @ii mR > (= 42.9-0ubuntu8)
Broken linux-generic:amd64 Depends on linux-image-generic:amd64 < none | 6.8.0-45.45 @hn pumH > (= 6.8.0-45.45)

ubuntu-bug ubuntu-release-upgrader-core output on Broken apps
Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 27
Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 27
Investigating (0) coreutils:amd64 < 8.32-4.1ubuntu1.2 -> 9.4-3ubuntu6 @pi umU Ib >
Broken coreutils:amd64 Breaks on usrmerge:amd64 < 25ubuntu2 @ii mK > (< 39)
  Considering usrmerge:amd64 -3 as a solution to coreutils:amd64 5113
  Added usrmerge:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete usrmerge:amd64 < 25ubuntu2 @ii mK > FU=0
  Fixing coreutils:amd64 via remove of usrmerge:amd64
Investigating (0) python3:amd64 < 3.10.6-1~22.04.1 -> 3.12.3-0ubuntu2 @ii umU Ib >
Broken python3:amd64 Conflicts on python3-distutils:amd64 < 3.10.8-1~22.04 @ri mK Ib >
  Considering python3-distutils:amd64 -2 as a solution to python3:amd64 674
  Added python3-distutils:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete python3-distutils:amd64 < 3.10.8-1~22.04 @ri mK Ib > FU=0
  Fixing python3:amd64 via remove of python3-distutils:amd64
Investigating (0) liblxqt1:amd64 < none -> 1.4.0-0ubuntu3 @un uN Ib >
Broken liblxqt1:amd64 Breaks on liblxqt0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ri mK > (< 0.99)
  Considering liblxqt0:amd64 -3 as a solution to liblxqt1:amd64 65
  Added liblxqt0:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete liblxqt0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ri mK > FU=0
  Fixing liblxqt1:amd64 via remove of liblxqt0:amd64
Investigating (0) libfm-qt14:amd64 < none -> 1.4.0-0ubuntu7 @un uN Ib >
Broken libfm-qt14:amd64 Breaks on libfm-qt9:amd64 < 0.17.1-0ubuntu2 @ii mK Ib >
  Considering libfm-qt9:amd64 -4 as a solution to libfm-qt14:amd64 25
  Added libfm-qt9:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete libfm-qt9:amd64 < 0.17.1-0ubuntu2 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
  Fixing libfm-qt14:amd64 via remove of libfm-qt9:amd64
Investigating (0) libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 < none -> 4.0.1-7.1ubuntu5.1 @un umN Ib >
Broken libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 Conflicts on libtss2-mu0:amd64 < 3.2.0-1ubuntu1.1 @ii gK >
  Considering libtss2-mu0:amd64 -3 as a solution to libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 17
  Added libtss2-mu0:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete libtss2-mu0:amd64 < 3.2.0-1ubuntu1.1 @ii gK > FU=0
  Fixing libtss2-mu-4.0.1-0t64:amd64 via remove of libtss2-mu0:amd64
Investigating (0) wireplumber:amd64 < none -> 0.4.17-1ubuntu4 @un umN Ib >
Broken wireplumber:amd64 Conflicts on pipewire-media-session:amd64 < 0.4.1-2ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib >
  Considering pipewire-media-session:amd64 -3 as a solution to wireplumber:amd64 14
  Added pipewire-media-session:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete pipewire-media-session:amd64 < 0.4.1-2ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
  Fixing wireplumber:amd64 via remove of pipewire-media-session:amd64
Investigating (0) liblxqt-globalkeys1:amd64 < none -> 1.4.0-0ubuntu4 @un uN Ib >
Broken liblxqt-globalkeys1:amd64 Breaks on liblxqt-globalkeys0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 0.99.0)
  Considering liblxqt-globalkeys0:amd64 -2 as a solution to liblxqt-globalkeys1:amd64 11
  Added liblxqt-globalkeys0:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete liblxqt-globalkeys0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK > FU=0
  Fixing liblxqt-globalkeys1:amd64 via remove of liblxqt-globalkeys0:amd64
Investigating (0) libkwinglutils14:amd64 < none -> 4:5.27.11-0ubuntu3 @un uN Ib >
Broken libkwinglutils14:amd64 Breaks on libkwinglutils13:amd64 < 4:5.24.7-0ubuntu0.2 @ii mK >
  Considering libkwinglutils13:amd64 -2 as a solution to libkwinglutils14:amd64 9
  Added libkwinglutils13:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete libkwinglutils13:amd64 < 4:5.24.7-0ubuntu0.2 @ii mK > FU=0
  Fixing libkwinglutils14:amd64 via remove of libkwinglutils13:amd64
Investigating (0) libkf5screen-data:amd64 < none -> 4:5.27.11-0ubuntu2 @un uN Ib >
Broken libkf5screen-data:amd64 Breaks on libkf5screen7:amd64 < 4:5.24.4-0ubuntu1 @ii mK > (< 4:5.27.0~)
  Considering libkf5screen7:amd64 -3 as a solution to libkf5screen-data:amd64 8
  Added libkf5screen7:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete libkf5screen7:amd64 < 4:5.24.4-0ubuntu1 @ii mK > FU=0
  Fixing libkf5screen-data:amd64 via remove of libkf5screen7:amd64
Investigating (0) libkwineffects14:amd64 < none -> 4:5.27.11-0ubuntu3 @un uN Ib >
Broken libkwineffects14:amd64 Breaks on libkwineffects13:amd64 < 4:5.24.7-0ubuntu0.2 @ii mK Ib >
  Considering libkwineffects13:amd64 -3 as a solution to libkwineffects14:amd64 7
  Added libkwineffects13:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete libkwineffects13:amd64 < 4:5.24.7-0ubuntu0.2 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
  Fixing libkwineffects14:amd64 via remove of libkwineffects13:amd64
Investigating (0) pipewire-audio:amd64 < none -> 1.0.5-1ubuntu1 @un uN Ib >
Broken pipewire-audio:amd64 Conflicts on pulseaudio:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 -> 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umU >
  Considering pulseaudio:amd64 22 as a solution to pipewire-audio:amd64 7
  MarkKeep pipewire-audio:amd64 < none -> 1.0.5-1ubuntu1 @un uN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back pipewire-audio:amd64 rather than change pulseaudio:amd64
Investigating (0) libqtermwidget5-1:amd64 < none -> 1.4.0-0ubuntu3 @un uN Ib >
Broken libqtermwidget5-1:amd64 Breaks on libqtermwidget5-0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > (< 0.99.0)
  Considering libqtermwidget5-0:amd64 -3 as a solution to libqtermwidget5-1:amd64 7
  Added libqtermwidget5-0:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete libqtermwidget5-0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
  Fixing libqtermwidget5-1:amd64 via remove of libqtermwidget5-0:amd64
Investigating (0) liblxqt-globalkeys-ui1:amd64 < none -> 1.4.0-0ubuntu4 @un uN Ib >
Broken liblxqt-globalkeys-ui1:amd64 Breaks on liblxqt-globalkeys-ui0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > (< 0.99.0)
  Considering liblxqt-globalkeys-ui0:amd64 -3 as a solution to liblxqt-globalkeys-ui1:amd64 4
  Added liblxqt-globalkeys-ui0:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete liblxqt-globalkeys-ui0:amd64 < 0.17.0-0ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
  Fixing liblxqt-globalkeys-ui1:amd64 via remove of liblxqt-globalkeys-ui0:amd64
Investigating (0) systemd-resolved:i386 < none -> 255.4-1ubuntu8.4 @un umN Ib >
Broken systemd-resolved:i386 Depends on libsystemd-shared:i386 < none | 255.4-1ubuntu8.4 @un umH > (= 255.4-1ubuntu8.4)
  Considering libsystemd-shared:i386 0 as a solution to systemd-resolved:i386 3
  MarkKeep systemd-resolved:i386 < none -> 255.4-1ubuntu8.4 @un umN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back systemd-resolved:i386 rather than change libsystemd-shared:i386
Investigating (0) libiw30t64:amd64 < none -> 30~pre9-16.1ubuntu2 @un uN Ib >
Broken libiw30t64:amd64 Conflicts on libiw30:amd64 < 30~pre9-13.1ubuntu4 @ii mK > (< 30~pre9-16.1ubuntu2)
  Considering libiw30:amd64 -3 as a solution to libiw30t64:amd64 2
  Added libiw30:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete libiw30:amd64 < 30~pre9-13.1ubuntu4 @ii mK > FU=0
  Fixing libiw30t64:amd64 via remove of libiw30:amd64
Investigating (0) libsgutils2-1.46-2:amd64 < none -> 1.46-3ubuntu4 @un uN Ib >
Broken libsgutils2-1.46-2:amd64 Breaks on libsgutils2-2:amd64 < 1.46-1ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii mK > (< 1.46-3ubuntu2)
  Considering libsgutils2-2:amd64 -3 as a solution to libsgutils2-1.46-2:amd64 1
  Added libsgutils2-2:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete libsgutils2-2:amd64 < 1.46-1ubuntu0.22.04.1 @ii mK > FU=0
  Fixing libsgutils2-1.46-2:amd64 via remove of libsgutils2-2:amd64
Investigating (0) pipewire-alsa:amd64 < none -> 1.0.5-1ubuntu1 @un uN Ib >
Broken pipewire-alsa:amd64 Conflicts on pulseaudio:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 -> 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umU >
  Considering pulseaudio:amd64 22 as a solution to pipewire-alsa:amd64 1
  MarkKeep pipewire-alsa:amd64 < none -> 1.0.5-1ubuntu1 @un uN Ib > FU=0
  Holding Back pipewire-alsa:amd64 rather than change pulseaudio:amd64
Investigating (0) libkpmcore12:amd64 < none -> 23.08.5-0ubuntu3 @un uN Ib >
Broken libkpmcore12:amd64 Breaks on libkpmcore11:amd64 < 21.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii mK >
  Considering libkpmcore11:amd64 -3 as a solution to libkpmcore12:amd64 1
  Added libkpmcore11:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete libkpmcore11:amd64 < 21.12.3-0ubuntu1 @ii mK > FU=0
  Fixing libkpmcore12:amd64 via remove of libkpmcore11:amd64
Investigating (0) libgs-common:amd64 < none -> 10.02.1~dfsg1-0ubuntu7.3 @un uN Ib >
Broken libgs-common:amd64 Breaks on libgs9-common:amd64 < 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9 @ii mK > (< 10)
  Considering libgs9-common:amd64 -2 as a solution to libgs-common:amd64 0
  Added libgs9-common:amd64 to the remove list
  MarkDelete libgs9-common:amd64 < 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9 @ii mK > FU=0
  Fixing libgs-common:amd64 via remove of libgs9-common:amd64
Investigating (0) libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 Depends on gnome-desktop3-data:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu1 -> 44.0-5build2 @ri umU > (< 43~)
  Considering gnome-desktop3-data:amd64 35 as a solution to libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 -1
  Removing libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 rather than change gnome-desktop3-data:amd64
  MarkDelete libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu1 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) libfwupdplugin5:amd64 < 1.7.9-1~22.04.3 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libfwupdplugin5:amd64 Depends on libfwupd2:amd64 < 1.7.9-1~22.04.3 -> 1.9.24-1~24.04.1 @ii umU > (= 1.7.9-1~22.04.3)
  Considering libfwupd2:amd64 11 as a solution to libfwupdplugin5:amd64 -2
  Removing libfwupdplugin5:amd64 rather than change libfwupd2:amd64
  MarkDelete libfwupdplugin5:amd64 < 1.7.9-1~22.04.3 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) libgs9:amd64 < 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libgs9:amd64 Depends on libgs9-common:amd64 < 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9 @ii mR > (= 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9)
  Considering libgs9-common:amd64 -2 as a solution to libgs9:amd64 -2
  Removing libgs9:amd64 rather than change libgs9-common:amd64
  MarkDelete libgs9:amd64 < 9.55.0~dfsg1-0ubuntu5.9 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) python3.10-venv:amd64 < 3.10.12-1~22.04.6 @ii mK Ib >
Broken python3.10-venv:amd64 Depends on python3.10-distutils:amd64 < none @un mH >
  Considering python3-distutils:amd64 -2 as a solution to python3.10-venv:amd64 -2
  Removing python3.10-venv:amd64 rather than change python3.10-distutils:amd64
  MarkDelete python3.10-venv:amd64 < 3.10.12-1~22.04.6 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (0) libpulsedsp:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libpulsedsp:amd64 Depends on libpulse0:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 -> 1:16.1+dfsg1-2ubuntu10 @ii umU > (= 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2)
  Considering libpulse0:amd64 131 as a solution to libpulsedsp:amd64 -2
  Removing libpulsedsp:amd64 rather than change libpulse0:amd64
  MarkDelete libpulsedsp:amd64 < 1:15.99.1+dfsg1-1ubuntu2.2 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (1) libmutter-10-0:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu8 @ii mK Ib >
Broken libmutter-10-0:amd64 Depends on libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu1 @ii mR > (>= 3.36.0)
  Considering libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64 -1 as a solution to libmutter-10-0:amd64 -1
  Removing libmutter-10-0:amd64 rather than change libgnome-desktop-3-19:amd64
  MarkDelete libmutter-10-0:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu8 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Investigating (1) gir1.2-mutter-10:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu8 @ii mK Ib >
Broken gir1.2-mutter-10:amd64 Depends on libmutter-10-0:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu8 @ii mR > (= 42.9-0ubuntu8)
  Considering libmutter-10-0:amd64 -1 as a solution to gir1.2-mutter-10:amd64 -2
  Removing gir1.2-mutter-10:amd64 rather than change libmutter-10-0:amd64
  MarkDelete gir1.2-mutter-10:amd64 < 42.9-0ubuntu8 @ii mK Ib > FU=0
Done

Any suggestions?
my kernel is
6.8.0-45-generic
lsb_release -a : outputs
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS
Release:        22.04
Codename:       jammy

Thank you in advance.

Try https://askubuntu.com/questions/1524989/how-to-fix-broken-24-04-1-lts-upgrade-which-is-missing-necessary-software. If it does not work, you may have to reinstall Ubuntu 24.04

This question is similar to: How to fix broken 24.04.1 LTS upgrade which is missing necessary software?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@karel, I did come across the posted comment you shared, it is similar. But the solution there did not solve my problem.

@ArchismanPanigrahi, thank you for sharing. I ran the solution. And it looks like the nobel package does not support LTS development. After running the instructions, I tried to do the server release upgrade but it does not work because there are no LTS development for the nobel packages.

What do you mean by LTS development?
