Ubuntu 22.04-24.04 upgrade exited with download error - how to recover?
I had an account here but Launchpad login is failing, so I'm using a new one. Not my Ubuntu-day..
So, I launched the 24.04 upgrade from 22.04, using the GUI updater.
The whole preparation and download went fine. However, during the installation/configuration process, I got a Download failed error and I noticed the whole Network Manager had disappeared from Gnome Shell. Pretty weird but not concerning I thought, since the packages should have been downloaded already.
I closed the error window, and then the updater closed suddenly (crashed?), apparently while trying to revert the changes.
At this point I probably made a mistake, as I tried to restart the system.
The system restarted, but now the situation is:

I'm in a terminal - gdm.service is not found
no internet connection - ethernet card recognized but won't connect. dhcp not installed
lsb_release -a shows I'm still on 22.04/jammy
apt upgrade/dist-upgrade wants to remove a long list (>100) of packages
dpkg --configure -a does nothing
do-release-upgrade simply fails to connect

Could I ask for help on what to check/how to proceed? Even if I can find a LiveUSB I wouldn't know what to do.
If there's similar questions or other resources I'd kindly ask for a link, I only have the 5" of my smartphone available at the moment for reading/searching.

Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/q/1524989/124466

Not sure if duplicate, but I tried the steps: full-upgrade fails because it can't download few packages. Maybe I'll try to download them manually and put them in apt's cache (it's maybe 20). Would you advise against it?

I would advise you download ubuntu 24.04 on a friend's computer, flash it on a usb drive and perform s fresh install

I hear you, but if I wanted to fresh install I'd have prepared for it already.. guess I'll try this workaround first, might not work but if it does I'd spare myself a lot of tedious configurations

In future, please create a fail safe backup of your configuration files, and make an installation script so that you can restore your system easily

I succeeded in that way. I finally had also to chroot from a LiveUSB and reinstall ubuntu-desktop^ to have a running system. Though for some reason most of the update advantage got lost (many packages/programs missing)...
The configuration files are anyway safe or savable. I'm not sure what the installation script would do, but also I start to shake as to why I should be dealing with all of that for a system update..

Is this fixed? Then please write your solution as an answer

I always do a fresh clean install of Ubuntu. I move from LTS to LTS.

The solution was essentially to follow the indications of the first answer here, with some tweaks because of the missing connection.
So, first verify that /etc/apt/sources.list and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources have the word noble instead of jammy. The link above has the commands to fix that.
Then, try sudo apt full-upgrade. If it works, great! If some packages need to be downloaded and the connection is not working (as in my case), chrooting from a LiveUSB is necessary for the download only - some updates may not work from chroot, especially e.g. grub.
After launching the LiveUSB and setting up the network, mount the internal harddrive, copy the file /etc/resolv.conf from the LiveUSB to it (to 'transfer' the connection, ref. here), and chroot in it (e.g. sudo chroot /media/internalHD).
If internet is now working (try ping), use
sudo apt --download-only full-upgrade
sudo apt install --reinstall --download-only ubuntu-desktop^ 

Then boot into the main system and repeat these commands without --download-only. This should restore a working desktop.
Programs may be missing because this is not the calculated upgrade, just a fix. You'll have to install them manually.
