mp4 codecs missing after upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
HW Info:

HW Model:                              Dell Inc. Latitude E6540
MEM:                                   4,0 GiB
Processor:                             Intel® Core™ i5-4300M × 4
Graphics:                              Intel® HD Graphics 4600 (HSW GT2)
SSD:                                   256,1 GB

SW Information:

firmware:                              A09
OS:                                    Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
Built OS:                              (null)
Type OS:                               64bit
Version GNOME:                         46
window system:                         Wayland
Kernel:                                Linux 6.8.0-45-generic

Ubuntu cannot open MP4 files after upgrade over Ubuntu 22 LTS
Codecs are missing and the searching machine dindn't find any suitable codec.
Everything run before upgrade.
Many thanks for any suggestion.
Jouza

Many thanks for your support and for your time Archisman.
I tried both commands:
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras and
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^
Installation was successful but without any result.
Additionally I realized that Ubuntu cannot open only mp4 from my drone DJI Mini4 PRO before processing in video editor. There is no problem after video processing and also with other mp4 files.
The issue with mp4 from drone before processing in video editor persists:

Missing:
meta/x-gst-fourcc-dbgi and
meta/x-gst-fourcc-djmd
I found only discussion about similar issue:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76305443/gstreamer-missing-decoder-meta-x-gst-fourcc-mebx
but didn't find any suitable SW for my codecs.
As said I had no problem before Ubuntu upgrade.
Any idea please?
Cheers!
Josef

You can install all codecs with the command
sudo apt install ubuntu-restricted-extras

Also, the upgrade path was buggy and sometimes it removes many packages present in default ubuntu installation. To reinstall all of them, execute the command
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^

(Note: The ^ is necessary in the command above)

What does the ^ do?

ubuntu-desktop is not a package, instead it's a task. so the roof char is required to not run into a package not found error. see also https://askubuntu.com/questions/211912/whats-the-caret-mean-in-apt-get

Zsh users should quote ubuntu-desktop^ (^ is used as a globbing metacharacter and unquoted unintended ^ will make commands fail at best)

For me ubuntu-desktop is a package (metapackage) and it depends on many stuff that makes up the default Ubuntu desktop installation.
